# How to use the mouse wheel to scroll in Tkinter, if it's in the frame the scrollbar is in?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I know that there is `.bind` and `.bind_all` methods, but there are problems with both of them. If you use `.bind`, it will only scroll if your cursor is in the empty space of that frame. If you use `.bind_all`, anywhere your mouse is, it will scroll if you use the mouse wheel. Is there a way to scroll it with the mouse wheel only when the cursor is in a certain frame?

Comment: Normally use `bind()` on the widget where scrolling is required and supported.  `Frame` is not a widget supporting scrolling.

Comment: I don't mean frame as in the Frame widget. I mean it as frame widgets in general(e.g. Canvas and LabelFrame). Also, using .bind() with a Canvas does the same thing with a Frame. The scrollbar is working, it's the binding that's not

Comment: You need to use `.bind` on all the widgets on which you want the mouse wheel scrolling to work (e.g. the labels in the frame scrolled in the canvas).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` binds of that widget to handle when the widget should have mouse wheel scrolling.

By using **`bind_all` with `<MouseWheel>` sequence only when the cursor is moved onto that widget** which can be checked with `<Enter>` sequence bind and unbinding the `<MouseWheel>` when the cursor is moved away from the widget.

*Have a look at this example.*

```py
import tkinter as tk


def set_mousewheel(widget, command):
    """Activate / deactivate mousewheel scrolling when 
    cursor is over / not over the widget respectively."""
    widget.bind("<Enter>", lambda _: widget.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', command))
    widget.bind("<Leave>", lambda _: widget.unbind_all('<MouseWheel>'))


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')

l0 = tk.Label(root, text='Hover and scroll on the labels.')
l0.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

l1 = tk.Label(root, text='0', bg='pink', width=10, height=5)
l1.pack(pady=10)
set_mousewheel(l1, lambda e: l1.config(text=e.delta))

l2 = tk.Label(root, text='0', bg='cyan', width=10, height=5)
l2.pack(pady=10)
set_mousewheel(l2, lambda e: l2.config(text=e.delta))

root.mainloop()
```

This example works every well with a Scrollable frame created with canvas, as the main frame inside canvas has multiple widgets and if we don't use `bind_all` over `bind` then the scrolling will not work if the cursor moves over the widget inside that scrollable frame.

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question perfectly.

Comment: Completely underrated and extremely helpful answer, cheers @Saad!